# How to suppress the decoding of encoded value of an html text box by Transformer of javax.xml.transform.Transformer

Tags: java, xml

I am trying to prepare an html using javax.xml.transform.Transformer from an xslt.

For that I am having below code ---

```
private static TransformerFactory factory;
    static {
        factory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
    }
    private static synchronized String process(Source xmlSource, Source xslSheet, HashMap<?, ?> params, String systemId)  {
            if ( systemId != null ){
                xslSheet.setSystemId(systemId);
            }
            ByteArrayOutputStream buf = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            StreamResult xmlResult = new StreamResult(buf);
            Transformer tfm;
            try {
                tfm = factory.newTransformer(xslSheet);
            } catch (TransformerConfigurationException e) {
                throw new IllegalStateException(e);
            }

            String result = ConversionUtils.toString(buf.toByteArray());
            IOUtils.close(buf);

            return result;
        }
```

I am using xsl for providing HTML definition to transformer object. Below is the xsl definition of the text box (for which I am facing issue[encoding is getting removed for its value]) --

```
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping='yes'>&lt;input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Keyword search ..." size="40" value="</xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="$search" disable-output-escaping='no'/>
<xsl:text disable-output-escaping='yes'>"/&gt;</xsl:text>
```

In the above code the text box value is populating from the 2nd line. In that line I am referring $search java variable which is having encoded value.

My issue is Transformer object is decoding that encoded text content while preparing the html. I dont want this default behavior.

Because of this default behavior, final html is having unescaped value for that text box. Due to this overall html page is getting vulnerable to XSS attack.

For example if I am having below value for text box --

```
1234"onmouseover="[window['location']='\x6a\x61\x76\x61\x73\x63\x72\x69\x70\x74\x3a\x61\x6c\x65\x72\x74\x2820\x29']"
```

After encoding this value will become -

```
1234\x22onmouseover=\x22[window[\x27location\x27]=\x27\\x6a\\x61\\x76\\x61\\x73\\x63\\x72\\x69\\x70\\x74\\x3a\\x61\\x6c\\x65\\x72\\x74\\x2820\\x29\x27]\x22
```

Above value will populate as text box content if we directly put that against a value of text box. But transformer object is again decoding this encoded value while preparing the html.

Is there any way, i can turn off this default behavior of transformer object.

Thanks in advance
Rahul

Comment: Provide an MVCE.

Comment: what is MVCE. Can you please elaborate.

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)